# How do I change to a new version of SQLite ( in.NET Core)?

Tags: .net, sqlite, .net-core

The operating environment is .NET 6 (on windows 10).

The package is Microsoft.Data.SqLite (version 6.0.3, now it is the latest version).

**The following code test output is version 3.34, this is a bit old, I want to use 3.37 or 3.38, how should I do?**
Or, I have downloaded the latest DLL (https://www.sqlite.org/download.html),
so do I need some way to configure it?

```
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;

var conn = new SqliteConnection();
Console.WriteLine(conn.ServerVersion);// result：3.34.1

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: What about https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite/

Comment: @Sir Rufo
Also no, and what I need to know is where do I need to configure to change the version to 3.8  ...Where can I change the version?

Comment: There is no version `3.7` or `3.8`. The latest version as reported by their [webiste](https://sqlite.org/releaselog/3_38_0.html) is **`3.38`** and from the [release history](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/news.wiki) the next version supporting `3.38` is scheduled. So the latest you can get for now is `3.37` and I gave you the link to the nuget package

Comment: @Sir Rufo
I am very sorry that I made a mistake in writing. Now I've changed the description in the question. The correct word should be 3.38 instead of 3.8. Thank you for your reply. System.Data.SqLite can be associated with 3.37, and 3.38 will be supported soon.  But Microsoft.Data.Sqlite can't be associated with 3.37 or 3.38?  Why? Or where can I see the information?  
 (I didn't find that information here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/?tabs=netcore-cli)

Comment: First: This question is not related to WPF or WinForms in **any** way, why are you adding that tags again?

Comment: Second: The association can only done by the nuget package owner. That is the whole magic. Ask them why they are not supporting the latest version.

Comment: @Sir Rufo I added these two tags because I thought that developers writing these apps would be more exposed to SQLite(with .net).  
Well, that seems to be the only result, but I didn't expect the microsoft.data.sqLite version to be so low, I hope I understood correctly.

Comment: [Microsoft.Data.Sqlite => Comparison to System.Data.SQLite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/sqlite/compare)

Comment: You should follow the guidelines here on stackoverflow and the main purpose is not to get **your** question answered, but to add good questions and answers for a lot of people which can search and find them. Using wrong tags is not helpful

Comment: @Jimi I've seen this before, but I'm not sure why the supported VERSION of SQLite is so far behind.  I couldn't find any information. I'm even wondering if it supports some way to switch to a higher version, hence the problem.

Comment: This API is not high-priority.